# Barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package not installed properly? Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I tried to install this package via composer and added the stuff needed for config/app.php and I got an error when I served it. It says "Call to undefined method Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::isDeferred()". I haven't used it in any of my controllers.

Comment: Did you add `Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,` to the providers in `app/config.php`?

Comment: you added the facade to the providers ... the facade is not a service provider, remove it from that list ... also this package more than likely has auto discovery